# Преобразование Map в список пар с использованием Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Имеем:

```
Map<String, List<Object>> map = fillMap();
```

Необходимо максимально элегантно преобразовать его в `List<Pair<String, Object>>` используя `Stream API` (`Pair` из apache lang3).

Например, было:

```
[
  a=[obj1,obj2,obj3],
  b=[obj4,obj5],
  c=[obj6,obj7]
]
```

хочу получить:

```
[
  Pair{a,obj1},
  Pair{a,obj2},
  Pair{a,obj3},
  Pair{b,obj4},
  Pair{b,obj5},
  Pair{c,obj6},
  Pair{c,obj7}
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно с помощью операции `flatMap` (вместо `Pair` - `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`), она принимает функцию, возвращающую `Stream` и встраивает элементы возвращенного потока в основной:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put( "a", Arrays.asList( "obj1", "obj2", "obj3" ) );
    map.put( "b", Arrays.asList( "obj4", "obj5" ) );
    map.put( "c", Arrays.asList( "obj6", "obj7" ) );

    System.out.println( map );

    List<Map.Entry<String, String>> list = map.entrySet().stream().flatMap( 
            entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                .map( listElement -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>( entry.getKey(), listElement ) )
        ).collect( Collectors.toList() );

    System.out.println( list );
```